# JSON data read as array of single characters

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I’m having a bit of an issue and was hoping someone has run across this and knows whats happening.

I’m calling our WebAPI to get data with `$resource`

(angularJS controller code)

```
 Controller.service.common.GetData.get({pubPolyData: objData}, function 
 (Response) {
                // success 
               Do stuff...

            }
```

(AngularJS Service)

```
GetData: $resource(myURL, {}),
```

through a APIController (this is a c# inheritable object) of type string.

I’m using `System.Net.WebClient();` which does a call to `response = client.DownloadString(theURI);` where `response` is what’s returned to the AngularJS.

This is what’s being returned in the ApiController

```
{"ObjectName":[{"ID":"123456","FormalName":"LastName, FirstName","SearchName":null,"Number":"xx-123-456789","OfficeName":"Some Office INC","Code":"987654","CompanyCode":"852","StateAbbr":"MN"}]}
```

…but as you can see what the call `Controller.service.common.GetTheData.get({sendData: objData}, function (myResponse)` is getting back for `myResponse` is in fact the correct data but split up in an array for each character

```
Response       [object (Resource)]
   _proto_     [object (Resource)]
   $promise    [object (Promise)]
   $resolved   true
   [0]         "{"
   [1]         "\"
   [2]         "O"
   [3]         "b"
   [4]         "j"
   [5]         "e"
   [0]         "c"
   [1]         "t"
   [2]         "N"
   [3]         "a"
   [4]         "m"
   [5]         "e"
   [0]         ":"
   [1]         "["
   [2]         "{"
   [3]         "I"
   [4]         "D"
   [5]         ":"
```

...etc

…what am I missing here?

Comment: This is impossible to answer.  Your JSON looks fine.  What about its content headers?  What is the code that receives this JSON?  Its your client-side code that is misinterpreting this as an array of characters, yet you didn't include it in the question.  Heck, show us your server-side code too.  As it stands, I'm voting to close.

Comment: "through a APIController of type string."  What does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the actual problem turned out to be getting an HttpResponseMessage(from remote WebAPI) inside a controller of type HttpResponseMessage(Local controller) and trying to pass that back to the $resource...no bueno!

What I actually did was to change the Local controller to type SimpleResponse..."T" being the model that you want to populate.  Yes, unfortunately if you need to call your remote controller like this for whatever reason you will have to duplicate the model on the local controller.

Once I had that, I Deserialized the Object and returned SimpleResponse to $resource and everything is happy!!

```
public class MyControllerController : ApiController {
    public SimpleResponse<DataModel> GET(string _inData) {            
        DataModel data = new DataModel();


            try {
                System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();

                String Domain = CallToGetValueFromWebConfig("WEBAPIURL", "value");
                String theURI = String.Format("{0}api/ApIControllerName?_inData={1}", Domain, _inData);


                client.BaseAddress = theURI;
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

                var json = client.DownloadString(theURI);

                data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataModel>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings() {
                    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
                });



            } catch (Exception ex) {
                EventLogging.AddExceptionEvent(EventLogging.EventID.WebApiDataGet, "Some error text", ex);
            }

        return new SimpleResponse<DataModel> { Data = data}; 
    }
}
}
```